# Visual C++ 2008 Express Download Link Dead?

Tags: c++, ide, download

the programming class I am currently taking uses Visual C++ 2008, and to work from home, we have the option of getting the express edition. I can't find the download link anywhere on the website, and the Microsoft support was absolutely no help. I also looked into just using Visual C++ 2010 but I heard there isn't much of a chance for compatability to work. If anyone has information on where I can get the Visual Studio 2008 express ISO or the C++ 2008 express download seperately, then let me know.

Comment: Express is always updated as soon as new version of VS becomes available.  Old versions are removed.  VS2012 is current.  Talk to your teacher about it.

Comment: if you need binary compatibility with visual c++ 2008 for some reason, [windows sdk 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18950) has visual c++ 2008, but you won't get an IDE with that

Comment: Nowdays, there also a [_Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7_](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).

Comment: Unfortunately @martineau's link no longer works. It links to an existing page but then the download links don't work. (Thanks as always, Microsoft.)

Comment: @tripleee: The link and download still work for me on 2019-11-11. I just tried it again and did a full download of the 83.8 MB pre-selected English language version just completed.

Comment: @martineau Sorry for the false alarm. It definitely said "This download is no longer available" earlier today, but I was able to fetch it now.

Comment: @tripleee: Because Internet… `;¬)`

Answer (score 211):

Direct link no more working for 2008.

**Just VS 2008 Express**

https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/5/8B5804AD-4990-40D0-A6AA-CE894CBBB3DC/VS2008ExpressENUX1397868.iso

**VS 2008 Express SP1**

https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/8/E/E8EEB394-7F42-4963-A2D8-29559B738298/VS2008ExpressWithSP1ENUX1504728.iso

Comment: Thank you for the help! I've been searching for this for hours...

Comment: The OP question may have been considered "off topic", but Nayana's answer was precisely what some of us needed to see.

Comment: I'd like to add my thanks to the list. I needed this badly.

Comment: That link seems to not work, but this one does as of October 2014 - http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/5/8B5804AD-4990-40D0-A6AA-CE894CBBB3DC/VS2008ExpressENUX1397868.iso

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: @Rasoolll the second link is more up-to-date than the first. the first is the original release, the second is that with service pack 1.

Answer (score 84):

You can download Visual Studio C++ 2008 from this link: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express with SP1](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279)

Comment: is that express edition?

Comment: Yes, this starts the 2008 Express installation.

Comment: Thankyou. Note that it's also available at an https link: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279 . (Stack Overflow suppresses the "https" in the link text.)

Comment: these links are dead