# C++ on Windows ME

Tags: c++

I have a Windows Vista computer and a Millennium Edition one. I want to start programming in C++ on Windows ME. I tried to find an answer but I didn't find one. **The question is... How can I install a (preferably from Microsoft) C++ compiler and libraries for my Windows ME?**  **Sorry for the low info**

Comment: Develop on the Vista machine.  Use the ME box as an office chair.

Comment: Try VS2008: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318560/visual-c-2008-express-download-link-dead (no guarantee, that it'll work on ME, but should work on Vista)

Answer (score 1):

You can download an ancient version of Visual Studio (maybe, just maybe, you can download Visual C++ Express 2005 from somewhere on the Internet) or you can download Codeblocks and GCC/MingW.

Comment: not compatible.(VC++E 2005)

Comment: maybe http://prdownload.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup_user.exe or http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-mingw47_32-x86-offline.exe  are...

Answer (score 0):

There is a old (now unsupported) tool/IDE from Microsoft called eVC, you can download and use it. I think you can try downloading it from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=16683

Comment: He specifically mentions Millennium Edition, not Mobile Edition.