# Tesseract - ambiguity in space and tab

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I had a tiff file, which contain some text separated by tabs (4 spaces). But when I extract text out of this tiff image file, i always get a single space between two columns. A sample example:

```
TIFF IMAGE:
col-a    col-b    col-c

desired output:
col-a    col-b    col-c

but I am getting the following:
col-a col-b col-c
```

I tried this with multiple images of same format, but the result is always the same.
How do I fix this issue ? Can I train tesseract to understand this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tesseract compresses consecutive spaces into one. You would need to modify `baseapi.cpp` to preserve the spaces. The code change can be found in the following posts:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/spaces/tesseract-ocr/lGBQiryHcrY/wy5a-L9O3i4J

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/spaces/tesseract-ocr/9nzPrBZ3118/b3W5GtsFPo0J

Comment: I am not a c++ programmer. I failed to open the project in vs 2005 and I do not have vs 2008 to compile the changes. How to get the compiled library?

Comment: You can still get VC++ 2008 Express. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318560/visual-c-2008-express-download-link-dead

Comment: @nguyenq : The code for the function `GetUtf8Text` has changed in the `baseapi.cpp` module, could you explain how to achieve the same in the current  installation of tesseract-ocr

Comment: No need to modify the source code as support for `preserve_interword_spaces` variable was added.

Comment: @nguyenq : But,the option of  `-c preserve_interword_spaces=1 ` via the _command line_, doesn't help the **right aligned** text, which converts to **left aligned**, as given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35660676/8030107) . Also, tabular data columns get concatenated almost, I want the columns to look separate and distinct for viewing purposes.

Comment: @aspiring1 Can you try with various PSM to see if it produces better results? Or put in a ticket with [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues) explaining deficiencies in current implementation; they may do something about it.

Answer (score 9):

After a very long research I found the solution. 
Here are the steps to follow

1. Upgrade your tesseract to 3.04
2. Create config.txt (Create a file in the directory where you input the image file)
3. In config file define "*preserve_interword_spaces*"
4. After the work *preserve_interword_spaces* give either 0 or 1. 
   Ex:

> preserve_interword_spaces 0

or

> preserve_interword_spaces 1

5. Test & Cheers!!!

Comment: Tested and working in 3.05, but the initial spacing (to the left of the first character) won't be preserved. Some extra processing would be required to insert a bogus character left of each column and then remove it in post-processing.