# Python 2.7.6 Installation Error on Windows 7 32bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, installation

I'm trying to install Python 2.7.6 on a HP-Mini 210 Netbook just to run some simple tasks.

I get the following error when the installer is doing "Status: Publishing Product Information"
[image: http://i.imgur.com/1a1DAAi.png]
I am trying to install Python but I'm running into following error:

The operating system is Windows 7 Start, Service Pack 1. 32bit (x86)

I've looked for quite a while trying to find a fix for this problem but can't find anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have MS Visual Studios installed on your machine and if yes, what year?

Comment: Yes, 2005. The default that comes with Windows 7 (which is compatible with Python's installer/setup)

Comment: I'd recommend getting 2008.  I had a similar issue, and I came away from it with the understanding that Python is very picky about which C compiler it uses.  Just a guess though. Also, you should check if your OS is capable of running Python (I'm not familiar with Windows 7 Start)

Comment: How would one get 2008, I've tried a bunch of downloads they're all wrong :S

Comment: It took me a week to find it when I had the issue, the first link in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318560/visual-c-2008-express-download-link-dead) is the direct download for the iso.