# invalid mex file missing dependent shared libraries

Tags: python, visual-c++, simulink

While trying to run a simulink model, run into the following error complained by Simulink:

> Invalid MEX-file  >
>   'C:...\sfun_WheelContacts.mexw64':
>   Missing dependent shared libraries: 'MSVCR90.dll' required by
>   'C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll->C:\Program
>   Files\PreScan\PreScan_8.4.0\bin\boost_python-vc140-mt-1_64.dll->C:\Program
>   Files\PreScan\PreScan_8.4.0\bin\impcore.dll->C:\Program
>   Files\PreScan\PreScan_8.4.0\bin\dataprovider.dll->C:\Program
>   Files\PreScan\PreScan_8.4.0\bin\interface_WheelContacts.dll->

I tried to look into the log of PreScan and Matlab integration but found nothing. Another action is to look for python27.dll. Confirm that it exists in c:\windows\system32.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to download the Visual Studio compiler used by Python 2.7. There are a couple of links for doing this in the answers here: [ide - Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318560/visual-c-2008-express-download-link-dead)

Comment: thanks. I tried your suggestion but my PC complains on the requirement of visual C++ 2008 SP1 update. And while I am trying to install Visual C++ 2008 sp1. It asks me to install Visual C++ 2008. I tried that too. But it failed. So I tried other methods.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that windows SDK for windows@7 has the necessary library. The action is to check the box " tools", "visual C++ compilers" and "Microsoft visual c++ 2010"

[image: snapshot of installation]